# type families: how to instantiate Bifunctor for a pair data type family?

Tags: haskell, type-families

I try to understand how data type families can be used to hide away a constructor. The trivial example given is a pair with operations to convert from and to ordinary pairs etc.). An instance for bifunctor does not compile; the error message is

> `src/TypeFamilyTest.hs:66:21`:
>       The first argument of `Bifunctor` should have kind `* -> * -> *`,
>         but `Pairs a b` has kind `ghc-prim-0.4.0.0:GHC.Prim.Constraint`
>
> In the instance declaration for `Bifunctor (Pairs a b)`

Trying `Bifunctor Pair where ...` I get another error message listing the same `GHC.Prim.Constraint`. What are the correct arguments for the instance and how will the context be passed?

```
class  Pairs a b where
    data Vec2 a b  

    mkPair :: (a,b) -> Vec2 a b   -- (FirstF a, SecondF a) -> a
    splitPair :: Vec2 a b -> (a,b)
    fstP ::  Vec2 a b -> a
    sndP ::  Vec2 a b -> b
    fstP = fst . splitPair
    sndP = snd . splitPair

instance ( ) => Bifunctor (Pairs a b) where
     bimap opv oph vh = mkPair  (opv . fstP $ vh, oph . sndP $ vh)
```

Comment: Data families are not about hiding constructors. Their constructors can be visible or hidden in all the same ways normal data types are. Data families are about non-parametric data types -- types which inspect their type arguments before deciding what their constructors look like.

Comment: A type class is not a class in the object-oriented sense. It does not encapsulate data and the operation that work on it.

Comment: The closest OOP notion of a Haskell `class` is a Java-like `interface`, and even this correspondence is loose.

Comment: You can define a type `newtype Vec2' a b = Vec2' (Vec2 a b)` and you can make instances of typeclasses for this type to your hearts content. However, this type is *not* a `Bifunctor`. The type of `bimap` would be `(Pairs a b, Pairs a' b') => (a -> a') -> (b -> b') -> Vec2' a b -> Vec2' a' b'`

Comment: thank you for the clarification. I do not understand why you introduce a newtype. what is the difference between Vec2 and Vec2'? both have two parameters? what is the benefit of the additional wrapper?

Answer (score 2):

The type error tells you everything. `Pair` is not the name of a datatype. It is the name of a class. `Pair a b :: Constraint` so `Pair :: * -> * -> Constraint`. `Bifunctor` can only be instantiated by datatypes of kind `* -> * -> *`.

I'm guessing you may have meant something like this:

```
newtype Pair a b = Vec2 { splitPair :: (a, b) }

fstP :: Pair a b -> a
fstP = fst . splitPair

sndP :: Pair a b -> b
sndP = snd . splitPair

instance Bifunctor Pair where
    bimap f g (Vec2 (x, y)) = Vec2 (f x, g y)
```

I don't understand why you originally made `Vec2` an associated type. I suspect this may be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/312922) - what are you really trying to achieve?

Comment: It looks like the OP is trying to simulate object-oriented programming, with `Pairs` being a type that encapsulates a `Vec2`. It's a coincidence that their attempt is syntactically correct.

Comment: i appreciate the helpful answers. i was trying to reduce clutter in a program where i feel i have too many classes and started experimentation with associated type. i now understand better, what associated types are useful for and will use a solution along the lines proposed.  - thank you!